# How to separate an integer by comma for every three digits

Tags: c++

I want to input an integer, like `123456789`, and I want to output the integer like this: `123,456,789`.

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
using namespace std;

char* separate(int);
char* inttostr(int);
int main() {
    int n;
    char* p;
    cin >> n;
    p = separate(n);
    cout << p;
    return 1;
}

char* separate(int num) {
    char* p1, *p2 = inttostr(num), *p3, *pt;
    int count = 1;
    p1 = p2;
    while (*p2++ != '\0');
    p3 = p2 - 1;
    p2 = p2 - 2;
    while (p2 > p1) {
        if (count == 3) {
            pt = p3++;
            while (pt >= p2)
                *(pt + 1) = *pt--;
            *p2 = ',';
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        p2--;
    }
    return p1;
}

char* inttostr(int num) {}
```

And i don't know what to do next in the `inttostr`. Can anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
// The inputted number. Keep this as a string, it's easier to deal with.
std::string     input;

// Get the input line.
std::cout << "Input a number:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> input;

// After every third character, we insert a comma. Go backwards so the leftovers are to the left.
for( int i = input.size() - 3; i > 0; i -= 3 )
{
    input.insert(  input.begin() + i, ',' );
}

// Output the number.
std::cout << "The number is: " << input << std::endl;
```

The answer is to learn about std::string, stop using C functions like malloc unless you're actually using C, and avoid raw pointers. Abstraction is good.

Comment: thanks,your solution is perfect.but can you just figure out this question with my unfinished code,because i am eager to learn some pointer thing or what.Ok,it's my homework and I have no way to solve it.please.thank you.

Comment: You can use std::to_string to convert from an int to a string. Do you need to make inttostr yourself?

Comment: school give me the code ,I could not change it but have to finish the rest part.I don't think I have it done.It's amazing that you can understand Chinglish.LOL.